# Jquery and css references are blocking page rendering in Asp.net on IE7 compatibility

Tags: css, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-7

My Asp.net application was designed to work with **IE 7 compatibility** (through X-UA-Compatible).  Recently I added latest **Jquery (1.11.1 version) and css** inline references to my project to include datepicker control in forms. Everything is working fine but on random postbacks **page rendering is being blocked** by Jquery and css references.

If I remove either of it (**Jquery/css references or IE7 compatibility meta tag**) from my master page then everything works fine.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

or

```
<link href="css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I need **IE 7 compatibility meta tag** in master page to render styles correctly as it was designed to render styles in IE7 and also i need **Jquery references** to use datepicker and to do few validations. Both are very necessary to my project.

I know this is very weird issue I have never experienced before. I am not sure how to resolve this issue.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by adding IE7 compatibility through server side instead of adding it in client side (aspx pages).

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.AddHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=7"); 
    }
```

Adding IE7 meta tag in aspx page is creating rendering problems. Now everything is working fine as expected. I am not getting any page rendering problems on using Jquery files in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are using jQuery version 2.x which is not supported in IE7. See their [Browser Support](http://jquery.com/browser-support/) page for more details.

I recommend you to use a lower version (1.x) or add it for older IE versions only using  `<!--[if lt IE 9]>`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, am using 1.11.1 version of Jquery. it shouldn't be a problem as it supports from IE6 +